# I can't move the logo on my website

Tags: html, css

I've been writing this website for a few days now and have gotten into trouble with my logo position. I can't seem to move it not matter how much I try. Can anyone suggest how I can do this? PS. (I'm still learning css.)

HTML:

```
<div class="logofx">
<a href="index.html"> <img src="images\logo.png"> </a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logofx img {

top:300px;
left:50px;

-webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 5s ease;
-o-transition: all 5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 5s ease;
transition: all 5s ease;          
}

.logofx img:hover {
-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(333deg);

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. " Can anyone suggest how I can do this". Do what..? can you be specific about what exactly you want to do, where exactly you want to position the logo..?

Comment: "**.. can't move ...**" ?? What move? You are just trying to `-webkit-filter: hue-rotate` which is working just fine. You are not trying to move anything.

Comment: The title says it all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `position:relative`, `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` (depending on the specific desired effect*).

By default, elements have `position:static` and statically-positioned elements are unaffected by `left/top/right/bottom` adjustments.

---

*Effects:

- `position:relative` moves the element by the amount specified, but other elements behave like it hasn't moved. If you want other elements to move too, consider using `margin` properties instead.
- `position:absolute` moves the element to be placed relative to the nearest `position:relative` container (or the whole document, if there is none).
- `position:fixed` fixes the element in the browser window, using the `left/top` as coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Set `position: fixed`

```
.logofx img {
  position: fixed;
  top:300px;
  left:50px;

  -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 5s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 5s ease;
  transition: all 5s ease;          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about margins instead?

```
    .logofx img {
    margin:300px 0 0 50px;
    display:block;
    -webkit-transition: all 5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 5s ease;
    transition: all 5s ease;          
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

HTMl:

```
<div class="logo"><div class="logofx">
<a href="index.html"> <img src="images\logo.png"> </a>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.logo{position:relative;}
.logofx{position:absolute; top:10px; left:10px;}
```

Try this code this will help you .Kindly put the top and left at correct pixel or move where you want using top and left property.